# expect script works while invoking individually but not as a salt state

Tags: bash, expect, salt-stack

I'm trying to do scp as well as ssh through expect. Below script works if I invoke it directly from terminal like `/usr/bin/expect myexpect.sh` but when I ran it using salt, the first scp command works where the second ssh fails.

`myexpect.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 240

spawn scp apps.tar.gz /srv/salt/integration/serverclass_merged.conf foo@10.10.10.10:/home/foo
expect "password:"
send "password\n";
expect eof

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no foo@10.10.10.10 "cd /home/foo;tar --strip-components=1 -xzvf apps.tar.gz -C /opt/apps/;cp serverclass_merged.conf /opt/local/serverclass.conf"
expect "assword:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

Relevant salt state looks like,

`st.sls`

```
copy_apps:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /usr/bin/expect /home/ocdn_adm/myexpect.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about [salt-stack](/questions/tagged/salt-stack) but I suspect it's not running your Expect script from a pty. So replace `interact` with `expect eof` (or `expect -timeout 12345 eof` if necessary). `interact` works only when stdin is on a tty/pty.