# How can I prevent `expect` from exiting at EOF when reading data from stdin?

Tags: bash, expect

When I run `echo "passphrase" | expect expect.exp "hostname"`, everything works fine, but `expect` exits immediately.

## expect.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set passphrase [gets stdin]

set hostname [lindex $argv 0]

spawn ssh admin@$hostname
expect "passphrase"
send "$passphrase\r"
expect "admin@$hostname"
send "clear\r"
interact
```

Comment: Show output of `admin@$hostname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interact` does not work when *stdin* is not a tty. You can pass the password as a command line option, just like the hostname.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do you know where I can find info about this in the docs?

Comment: i did not find this in the doc. its based on my testing result. :)

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698791/expect-script-works-while-invoking-individually-but-not-as-a-salt-state

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the environment to pass the passphrase:

```
# shell code
export passphrase="pass phrase"
expect expect.exp hostname

# expect code
...
send "$env(passphrase)\r"
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Will report back in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842220/4579271. Thanks!